# Rails Model Methods not working well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have methods that i'm trying to test in my models, but they're not working well, it doesn't seem to return false when it should- any suggestions?

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :check_duplicate_section
def check_duplicate_section
    all_registrations = Registration.all
    all_registrations.each do |reg|
        puts reg.section_id
        if reg.section_id == self.section_id && reg.student_id == self.student_id 
        errors.add(:registration, "Already exists")
        return false
        end
    return true
end
end
```

Test File: (@bruce is defined earlier)

```
class RegistrationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

should "not allow invalid student registrations" do
    @mike = FactoryGirl.create(:student, :first_name => "Mike")
    good_reg = FactoryGirl.build(:registration, :section => @section2, :student => @mike)
    bad_reg = FactoryGirl.build(:registration, :section => @section1, :student => @bruce)
    bad_reg2 = FactoryGirl.build(:registration, :section => @section2, :student => @mike)
    assert_equal true, good_reg.valid?
    assert_equal false, bad_reg.valid?
    assert_equal false, bad_reg2.valid?
```

Answer (score 1):

from the looks of what you're trying to do with `check_duplicate_section`, it's better to use the built in `uniqueness` validation

```
validates :section_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

If you don't want to use this, change your method to

```
def check_duplicate_section
  if Registration.where(section_id: self.section_id, student_id: self.student_id).exists?
    errors.add :registration, "Already exists"
  end
end
```

Also, in your tests, you are using `build` which doesn't save anything to the db.  You should use `create` or better yet, use mocks to force the returned values of your db queries.

The good thing about using the built in validation approach is you don't need to test it because it should work.